# Find or list files in current DIR that were created before TODAY (at 00:00)

Tags: terminal, find

I have been thoroughly searching for this unsuccesfully.
I need a Terminal command in mac that would retrieve me a list of files in the current directory (not including subdirectories) created before today at 00:00.

system: MacOS Catalina

Thanks a thousand, 
EG

Comment: What filesystem is this about? Some filesystems don't store birth time, so it may turn out you simply cannot do this. Please [edit] the question and add specify the filesystem.

Comment: Im on Mac Catalina.

Comment: Get %Y%m%d from date, and pad it with time 00:00:00. Touch a reference file with that date. Use find with ! -newer myRefFile.

Comment: Would this find files older than today? Could you pass me the line? I'm no coder.

Comment: It's not a one-liner -- 6 lines: date, touch, for, ls, unset, rm, after you take out the diagnostics and stuff it into a script. Commands and results posted as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . ! -name . -prune ! -newermt 00:00
```

Would report the files (of any type, including directory) last modified before 00:00 this morning.

```
find . ! -name . -prune ! -newerBt 00:00
```

Would report the files *born* before 00:00 this morning.

The former would be more relevant as the creation time of the *contents* of the file, the latter as the time where the file spawned into existence (though not necessarily by that name, and note that files are initially created empty, with the contents added later on).

That works with FreeBSD `find`, I suppose that should also work on macOS as macOS utilities are generally based  on FreeBSD's.

With `zsh` (using *modification time*):

```
autoload before
print -rC1 -- *(Ne[before 00:00])
```

For symlinks, the `find` approaches will look at the timestamps of the symlinks themselves, while `zsh`'s `before` function looks at the file they point to. You can add the `-L` option to `find` to get the same behaviour as in `zsh`.

POSIXly, you could do:

```
touch -t "$(date +%Y%m%d0000)" ~/.today &&
  find -L . ! -name . -prune ! -newer ~/.today
```

Comment: Thanks, how do you use instead of the dot to make it only look in current directory or just one level directory?

Comment: You need `-maxdepth 1` to avoid descending more that one level below ./ but I am unclear if OSX has that GNU extension. On other systems, I have let find run through everything and then filtered the output with `awk '-F/' 'NF == 2'` (somewhat inefficient though).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, I had missed that part of the OP's requirement. You'd need both `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`, or `-depth 1` with some find implementations, or better use the standard `-prune` as in my latest edit.

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein, see edit.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Is there any generic way to determine whether -newerBt is supported? I get: find: This system does not provide a way to find the birth time of a file. I guess you could run `find . -newerBt 00:00 /dev/null` first, and check the status.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, note that those are not standard `find` options (first appeared as a user-contributed patch for some BSD IIRC), and where supported, the syntax for the timestamp differs between  version, and where supported, you also need the libc and kernel to supply an API to retrieve it, and you also need the underlying FS to store the information.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Possibly not a solution for Mac Catalina then. I'm beginning to prefer my alternative old-school bash script.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, why not?

Answer (score 0):

A very naive way of doing this could be to use the `find` utility and then doing a grep on the date that you want to filter for. For instance, given that you want to search for all files that are **modified** on May 24th, you can do:

```
$ find . -type f -ls | grep "May 24"
```

If you need just the filename and not the complete dump, you can use `xargs`:

```
$ find . -type f -ls | grep -o "May 24.*" | awk '{print $4}' | xargs basename
```

Do make note of the fact that when you run `find` with `-ls`, the time you see is the file *modification* time and not the *creation* date.

Comment: Thanks. How to possibly make the specified date always the current date?

Comment: You can use `date "+%b %d"` to get the current date in the format "Mon XX". Not sure if that was what you were after?

Comment: You can use command substitution to get this `find . -type f -ls | grep "$(date '+%b %d')" | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs basename`

Comment: Thanks. I ran that command in my Desktop where I have several text files (some created yesterday and some today) but it returns nothing. I just want it to return those created before today.

Comment: Can you share sample output for the `ls -al` command? I'm curious to see why it's not working.

Comment: It is not recommended to parse ls output, but if you have to look at times, at least make comparisons consistent by using `ls -l --time-style=long-iso` or `ls -l --time-style=full-iso`.

Answer (score 0):

I put in "-d '9 days ago' " to limit my output, and as an example. Obviously, put this in a script and weed out the diagnostics. I use an array so ls only needs to run once. You might find the array useful for your next process, too.

```
Paul--) #.. Get a timestamp in touch format.
Paul--) Midnight="$( date -d '9 days ago' '+%Y%m%d0000.00' )"
Paul--) declare -p Midnight
declare -- Midnight="202005160000.00"
Paul--) #.. Make a reference file.
Paul--) touch -t "${Midnight}" refDate.tmp
Paul--) ls -l refDate.tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul paul 0 May 16 00:00 refDate.tmp
Paul--) #.. Add olderThan Names to an array.
Paul--) for fn in *; do
    [[ -f "${fn}" && "${fn}" -ot refDate.tmp ]] &&
        Want+=( "${fn}" )
done
Paul--) echo Count ${#Want[@]}
Count 7
Paul--) #.. List the files.
Paul--) ls -ld "${Want[@]}"
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul paul    1014 May 14 18:03 Algorithm_2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul paul 1507999 May 14 23:15 Ram.1e12E
-r-------- 1 paul paul    1149 May 14 22:14 Ramanujan.array.V01
-r-------- 1 paul paul    1635 May 14 21:45 Ramanujan.sort.V01
-r-------- 1 paul paul    1773 May 14 10:38 Ramanujan.V06
-r-------- 1 paul paul    1747 May 15 19:12 Ramanujan.V07
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul paul    4183 May 14 23:44 Test.log
Paul--) #.. Tidy up.
Paul--) unset Want; rm -f refDate.tmp
```

Comment: As mentioned above by Kamil, the -ot test refers to modified time, not initial creation time. I never saw much use for create time, so I hope modified is what you really need.